# Remove duplicates on multiple criteria in power query or dax/powerbi

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerquery

Currently I'm working on removing duplicate values from multiple criteria. My main data is only for 3 columns i.e Machine, Product and Source and last 2 columns are Concat and Count. Concat is used for unique combination for Machine+Product+Source.

| machine | Product | Source | Concat | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m1 | S | 983 | m1S983 | 1 |
| m1 | S | cmdd | m1Scmdd | 2 |
| m1 | S | cmdd | m1Scmdd | 2 |
| m1 | A | cmdd | m1Acmdd | 2 |
| m1 | A | cmdd | m1Acmdd | 2 |
| m1 | B | 983 | m1B983 | 2 |
| m1 | B | 983 | m1B983 | 2 |

In above table machine, product and source are my main data source columns. I've added "concat" column to get unique values and then I used Countif formula in "Count" column.

My 1st step to remove duplicate rows on basis of concat column or where the count value is >1. Result is shown in below image

[image: Image 1 after using normal remove duplicate method] .

Step 2 is:

In above image I've to remove rows manually where Source criteria should always be "cmdd" and Product could be anything in large dataset. For example I've highlighted in yellow color for above image.

Below image is final result set where I remove a row based on above criteria mentioned.

[image: Image 2]

I'm not sure how to user powerquery or dax to remove values based on multiple criteria.
on how to remove row where criteria should always set to "cmdd" from "Source" column and product could be anything from large dataset.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: please post sample data as text not images.  Also, if your data has Product=B and Source=983 not sure how you got that from  criteria as "cmdd" and "s"

Comment: @horseyride: I've added data in usable format  (1st table only ) and remove image. My 1st step is remove duplicate rows on basis of concat column. My 2nd step is to remove rows where 1st criteria is always set to Source value: "cmdd" and 2nd criteria should change as per product values changes.

Comment: Sorry, I still dont understand how 1st criteria is always set to Source value: "cmdd" can generate a row that has 983 in Source. Maybe someone else can help

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, click select the first three columns, right click, remove duplicates

Then use arrow atop the Product and Source column to get dropdown and filter for your criteria

Home ... remove rows .. remove top row, if thats what you then need